# ignore self-signed, expired ssl certificate in tortoise svn

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, ssl-certificate

Tortoise SVN will not let me access an svn repository that has a self signed **and** expired ssl certificate.

Is there a config somewhere to tell it that I want to trust that certificate anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem with SCPlugin on mac - the workaround was to use the command line version of svn, which does give you a prompt to permanently ignore the certificate error, after which the gui (which shares the same settings) will work fine. I can't be sure, but I suspect the same approach may work for TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Thanks, works under Windows too. Changed to my working copy folder and typed `svn log`. Then accepted cert permanently.

Answer (score 5):

If TortoiseSVN insists in asking to accept the certificate every time although you have clicked in "Accept permanently", go to the TortoiseSVN configuration and clear the authentication cache.

Comment: thanks a lot! was trying to find answer several days